# Script to download the pdf directly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a script which appends parts of a URL and downloads them to a specific folder.
For Example :Link 1: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf
Link 2: https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1981.nc

When you go to link 2 file gets downloaded automatically, whereas link 1 will just open the file in browser. Can I turn link 1 to act as link 2.?

Comment: what have you tried? can you show us what code have you used to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 1):

It already does act that way.  Both links respond with the content of the files, the only difference is that your browser downloads the pdf and then displays it because internally it knows how to.  This can be disabled in your settings if you want.

When it comes to writing a python script like you mention in the title both behave in the same way already.

for example lines below could be used as a script to get both files:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url1 = "https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_1981.nc"
>>> url2 = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
>>> r1 = requests.get(url1)
>>> r2 = requests.get(url2)
>>> with open("pr_1981.nc","wb") as file1:
        file1.write(r1.content)
>>> with open("dummy.pdf", "wb") as file2:
        file2.write(r2.content)
```